# Генерация картинки

Tags: javascript, json, изображения

Я делаю запрос к API  и она мне возвращает объект или JSON.

Как на основе этих данных я смогу сгенерировать картинку? Например карточку погоды с 3-4 полями или результатами матча каких-то команд.

Рассматривал *html-to-image* и это должно сработать, но там по клику скачивание. А мне нужно что, бы сразу (самостоятельно) скачивалась в папку с проектом и я мог ее использовать.

Comment: Вы не можете автоматически ничего положить в папку на компе, система безобпастности не даст. Представляете, если бы можно было, какой-нибудь сайт то что уже вам на диске хаос устроил. Конечно само по себе скачивание можно запустить и автоматом, например кликнув JS-ом в ссылку с атрибутом `download`. Но куда качать, спрашивать при этом пользователя путь сохранения или нет, будет решать сам браузер.

Comment: А как я могу положить себе ее в проект? У меня не будет клиентской части. Только серверная.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515292/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment2720280_1515292) [aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot): Вы не можете автоматически ничего положить в папку на компе, система безобпастности не даст

Картинку можно сгенерировать с помощью [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) и его метода [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Для простоты в примере не буду реализовывать запрос к API, а просто каждый раз будут рандомные значения:

```js
const backgroundImageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
const generatedImageConatiner = document.querySelector('.generatedImage');

const downloadImage = async (url) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();

    img.src = url;
    img.crossOrigin = "use-credentials";

    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  })
}

const getRandomText = () => (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);

const getFakeData = async () => {
  const text1 = getRandomText();
  const text2 = getRandomText();
  
  return {text1, text2};
}

const generateImage = async () => {
  const background = await downloadImage(backgroundImageUrl);
  const data = await getFakeData();
  const text = `${data.text1} ${data.text2}`.toUpperCase();
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  canvas.width = 700;
  canvas.height = 400;
  
  const canvasMiddleX = canvas.width / 2;
  const canvasMiddleY = canvas.height / 2;

  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
  context.font = "40pt Calibri";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText(text, canvasMiddleX, canvasMiddleY);

  const generatedImageUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  const generatedImage = await downloadImage(generatedImageUrl);

  generatedImageConatiner.append(generatedImage);
}

generateImage();
```

```css
.generatedImage {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}

.generatedImage img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='generatedImage'></div>
```